# Unable to change image pixels using canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I've this code and I want to change a gray pixels to all while but it simply duplicates the testImage:

```
 $("body").append('<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>');
                var image = document.getElementById('testImage');
                var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
                canvas.width = image.width;
                canvas.height = image.height;
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
                var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                var data = imgData.data;
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4)
                    {

                            data[i] = data[i + 1] = data[i + 2] = data[i + 3] = 255;                        

                    }              

                ctx.putImageData(imgData, image.width, image.height);
```

What mistake am I making?

Comment: I guess ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0,0) is correct